# Dos campos excluyentes

Tags: php

tengo dos pequeños archivos de prueba: 1 pruebaEs.html y 2 procesapruebaEs.php.
En el archivo 1 tengo dos campos excluyentes: si se elige LenguaB no se puede elegir Arte o Música.
¿Cómo se puede poner en el archivo 2 alguna condición para que el servidor no devuelva un mensaje de error en la variable "bildemu" (arte o música), dado que la db no recibe una de las dos variables? Parece que se puede hacer con isset o empty, pero necesito un ejemplo práctico. Soy muy novato todavía. ¿Alguien me puede ayudar? Gracias por alguna idea.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
    <title>Prueba</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
        <script languaje="javascript">
            function habilita(form)
            {    
    form.bildemu[0].disabled = true;
    form.bildemu[1].disabled = true;
    }
function deshabilita(form)
    { 
        form.bildemu[0].disabled = false;
        form.bildemu[1].disabled = false;
    }
    </script>
</head>
    <body>
        <form action="procesaPrueba.php" method="post"> 
            <p>
            <label for="name">Apellido:</label>
            <input type="text" name="name"required id="name"=>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp
            <!--para introducir comentarios-->
            <label for="vorname">Nombre:</label>
            <input type="text" name="vorname"required id="vorname"></br>
            <i>Elige una lengua-B:</i>
            <input type="radio" name="b_sprache" value="Spanisch B"onClick="habilita(this.form)"> Español B
            <input type="radio" name="b_sprache" value="Italienisch B"onClick="habilita(this.form)"> Italiano B
            <input type="radio" name="b_sprache" value="Französisch B"onClick="habilita(this.form)"> Francés B </br> 
            <i>Para las clases 12/13 me inscribo en las siguientes asignaturas:</i></br>
            <input type="radio" name="bildemu"   value="Arte">
            <label for="Arte">Arte</label> 
            <input type="radio" name="bildemu"   value="Música">
            <label for="Musica">Música,</label>&nbsp; </br>
            <i>y</i>
            <input type="radio" name="ct" required id="ct" value="Computertechnik">
            <label for="ct">Técnica de ordenadores.</label></br>
            </br></br>
            <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
            <input type="reset">

            </br></br>
    </form>
</body>
```

```
<?php
     $bildemu=$_POST['bildemu'];
     $b_sprache=$_POST['b_sprache'];
     $name=$_POST['name'];
     $vorname=$_POST['vorname'];
     $ct=$_POST['ct'];
     $servername = "localhost";
     $username = "root";
     $password = "";
     $dbname = "schule3";

     $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
     if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection fallida: " . $conn->connect_error);
     } 

     $sql = "INSERT INTO schule3(name, vorname, b_sprache, bildemu, ct)
     VALUES ('$name', '$vorname', '$b_sprache','$bildemu','$ct',)";

     if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
     echo "das Formular wurde geschickt!";
     } else {
     echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
     }

     $conn->close();
```

?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

si lo que quieres es validar la `variable`bildmenu para que si va vacia no te mande error o eso es lo que entiendo que quieres hacer, seria algo asi.

```
$b_sprache=$_POST['b_sprache'];
$name=$_POST['name'];
$vorname=$_POST['vorname'];
$ct=$_POST['ct'];
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "schule3";

if(empty($_POST['bildemu'])){
$bildemu = '0';

$sql = "INSERT INTO schule3(name, vorname, b_sprache, bildemu, ct)
VALUES ('$name', '$vorname', '$b_sprache','$bildemu','$ct',)";

} else { 
$sql = "INSERT INTO schule3(name, vorname, b_sprache, bildemu, ct)
VALUES ('$name', '$vorname', '$b_sprache','$bildemu','$ct',)";
}
```

esta seria una manera otra podria ser así.

```
if(empty($_POST['bildemu'])){

$bildemu = '0';

} else {

$bildemu = $_POST['bildemu'];

}

$b_sprache=$_POST['b_sprache'];
$name=$_POST['name'];
$vorname=$_POST['vorname'];
$ct=$_POST['ct'];
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "schule3";

$sql = "INSERT INTO schule3(name, vorname, b_sprache, bildemu, ct)
VALUES ('$name', '$vorname', '$b_sprache','$bildemu','$ct',)";
```

en la primera recibes tus variables y al momento de hacer el `insert` es cuendo validas si va vacia que haga un `insert` y si no que haga el otro, en la segunda es la misma condición pero esta vez validas solo el campo si esta vacio el asignas un valor para que guarde algo en la `db`,espero te ayude.

Comment: Hola: los dos procedimientos funcionan: envían el formulario a la tabla con los datos elegidos:1 b-sprache  o 2 arte o música, pero devuelve el mensaje de error para 1: Notice: Undefined index: bildemu in C:\xampp\htdocs\Pruebas\procesaPruebaEs.php on line 15 y para 2:Notice: Undefined index: b_sprache in C:\xampp\htdocs\Pruebas\procesaPruebaEsB.php on line 14 ¿NO se podría evitar el mensaje de error? Muchas gracias de nuevo.

Comment: Funciona la mitad, quizá por un error mío en la primera parte del formulario. Me explico: si elijo una lengua-b (español, italiano o francés) entonces se anulan las opciones de arte y música,  y los datos pasan al formulario: italiano, bildemu 0 y tecnica de ord. (por ejemplo) Pero si elijo primero arte o música, no se anula b_sprache (lengua_b), entonces el servidor da un error en la variable b_sprache, porque no está anulada. A ver si puedo hacer esto y probar si funciona.

Comment: haber si te entendí cuando eliges arte o musica se anula para seleccionar lengua b

Comment: Solucionado!!! La solución estaba en añadir otra vez la secuencia if (empty ($_POST [' b_sprache'])){ ...  con la variable que daba el error!!

Comment: asi es era solo de esa manera no olvides aceptar la respuesta y brindar votos

Comment: ¿cómo se hace ?

Comment: para los votos es con flecha arriba y para aceptar la respuesta de la forma que lo hiciste saludos